# Adding degree symbol in roxygen2

Tags: r, documentation, r-markdown, roxygen2, roxygen

How to add degree symbol using roxygen2 for `R` documentation?

`°C`  works in pdf, but it html, it is shown as `Â°C`.

Here is the session info.

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

Comment: Two possibilities: try using the Unicode, like in `cat('\u00B0')`. Or maybe you need `Encoding: UTF-8` in your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Hum I've tested without the Encoding filed and without using explicit unicode, and the character `°` prints OK.

Comment: I am using `Encoding:UTF-8` and i have tried `\code{print('\u00B0')}`, but getting same result `Â°C`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your package (GitHub)?

Comment: @F.Privé My package is not in github yet. Moreover I think that non-ascii characters are not allowed in R or R documentation for CRAN.

Comment: You can try `\eqn{^{\circ}C}`

Answer (score 1):

To add any non-ASCII characters in `R` documentation using `roxygen2`, the encoding must be declared using the tag `@encoding`.

So when `°C` is used in the roxygen code, adding the tag `@encoding UTF-8` will render it correctly for html as well as pdf.

This can be checked with

```
path <- "path to Rd file"
tools::checkRd(path)
```

Comment: This does not work for me. If I use ä in roxygen2 documentation for a function, R changes it into gibberish in the .Rd file. It does add `\encoding{UTF-8}` at the top, but that's too late. The .Rd file is already incorrect.